# System UI has stopped after update Android 5.1

Tags: android, crash, system, updates

[SOLVED] I am facing a big problem. My app works normally before update Android 5.1. After upgrading my Nexus 5 to Android 5.1, app works well. But my users, who have Nexus 6 devices, report that they got error "System UI has stopped" after upgrading to 5.1. I haven't never got this error before. I don't understand what happened.

EDIT:
I finally found out what happened. It is a bug of Android 5.1 with screen capture permission. If user selects "Don't show again" tick box of screen capture permission dialog, then next time user will get System UI crash. So the only way to avoid it is that DO NOT SELECT "Don't show again".

Comment: post your logcat or else check ur manifest.xml

Comment: @prabhakaran: I haven't got any Nexus 6, so I have no logcat to show. Here's part of Manifest <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..."
 
    android:versionCode="14"

    android:versionName="2.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: remove android:targetSdkVersion="21"