# How to address MediaProjectionManager.createscreencaptureintent() leading to "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped"

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-capture

First, I believe this is the same issue as described by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007334/system-ui-has-stopped-after-update-android-5-1). I want to provide more details and be as specific as possible in the hope that some guru will come up with an elegant solution. This happens with **Android 5.1**

The following code

```
startActivityForResult(myMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SCREEN_RECORDING);
```

will show the following prompt to the user:

[image]

If the user **does not** select "Don't show again", everything will work exactly as expected.  Unfortunately, if "Don't show again" is selected, the same code will lead to the following prompt **from the next run**:
[image]

The device will go to the lock screen after the prompt.

Could anyone confirm this is caused by a system bug and offer a remedy without asking the user to avoid selecting "Don't show again"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anyone confirm this is caused by a system bug

If you are seeing the same Java stack trace as is reported in [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159196), then yes, this would appear to have been a system bug.

> and offer a remedy without asking the user to avoid selecting "Don't show again"?

Ask the user to upgrade their device. Apparently, this was fixed in 5.1.1.

Or, do not use `MediaProjectionManager`. The problem is not in your app, and so there is nothing that you can do to change the behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt answer.  Yes, I see exactly the same NPE exception in logcat. Is there comparable or even better alternative to using MediaProjectionManager for screen recording?

Comment: @Hong: No, sorry. Outside of rooted devices, `MediaProjectionManager` is your only option.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  MayI ask one more favor: how can I tell 5.1 from 5.1.1 in code?  They are the same API level.  Should I post another question for this?  I did a quick search, but could not find an answer.

Comment: @Hong: I am not sure what the best approach would be for that. Looking at `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` and seeing if it starts with `5.1.1` *might* work, but I don't know if there is a better solution.

Comment: Many thanks.  This will do it.  I have just tested Build.VERSION.RELEASE on a 5.1 and a 5.1.1 device and it is exactly 5.1 and 5.1.1 respectively.

Comment: @Hong: I worry that `RELEASE` may be more subject to manufacturer tinkering than are the API levels, so I would still use `startsWith()` instead of `equals()`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I will try to check API 22, then contains(5.1) and not contains(5.1.1) to catch the real 5.1 that deserves special warning.